# jQuery WYSIWYG which allows Canvas tag?

Tags: jquery, canvas, editor, wysiwyg

I'm trying to build a certain kind of text editor which also allows for the placement of drawable canvas sections within it. Most of the text editors I have been trying seem to be removing the canvas tag after a save or upon updating. Does anyone know of any text editors which allows for the canvas tag?

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: Never heard of such...Why the need to integrate text and canvas--would text plus a separate canvas suffice?

Comment: Are you sure that the canvas is removed from the content (that's easily fixable in whatever editor you're using), or are the contents of the canvas removed? because the canvas itself is a simple tag that doesn't store its contents, you must save and restore them using javascript.

Comment: They all seem to be removing the entire <canvas> tag. 
I could possibly implement a separate canvas element that gets overlaid, but it would start to become a real pain working out formatting and positioning for both the (dynamic) text content, and a canvas 'box'. I would think it would be much wiser to incorporate the canvas element within the text content if possible.

Thanks.